# Copy files to a new directory according to file names stored in a text file with Python 3.x

Tags: python, file, text, directory, copy

I have a txt file which is a config file for some software.

The format of content in the text file is like this:

txt1.txt:

```
image/icon/apple.png
image/icon/pear.png
image/icon/kiwi.png
```

Those png files are stored either in dir1 or dir2, I don't know which is in which. Those dirs are like:

```
dir1 = "C:\\files1\\image\\icon\\"
dir2 = "C:\\files2\\image\\icon\\"
```

Now I want to copy all the .png files from either dir1 or dir2 to a new folder.
Not sure with which logic I should go along. Can anyone give any insight?

Comment: Do you expect the images to be in both directories?

Comment: @Jmonsky hi, nope. Each image can only appear in one folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly changed txt1.txt to:

```
apple.png
pear.png
kiwi.png
```

This code should work for an arbitrary amount of directories to check for the given files.

```py
import os
import shutil

fileListingFile = "txt1.txt"
directories = [
    "C:\\files1\\image\\icon\\"
    "C:\\files2\\image\\icon\\"
]
outputDir = "C:\\outdir\\image\\icon"

with open(fileListingFile, "r") as file:
    fileNames = [file.strip() for file in file.readlines()]

for directory in directories:
    for file in fileNames:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, file)):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(directory, file), os.path.join(outputDir, file))
```